# Redirect everything with a specific TLD XAMPP vhost

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

So there are multiple domains leading to 1 web server
say:

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
...........
...........
```

They all would be redirected to http://example.com

Now in the Apache config for virtual hosts I'd have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias [SOMETHING THAT WOULD MATCH EVERY .COM DOMAIN]
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/onion"
</VirtualHost>
```

I need a piece of code (after ServerAlias) that would match any .com domain

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: **ServerAlias *.com** this one ?

Comment: seems to work :D thanks, I thought an asterisk only worked for subdomains :)

Comment: yes of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcard(*) to match multiple domain names to Apache virtual host. From the [original Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html)

> Many servers want to be accessible by more than one name. This is
>   possible with the ServerAlias directive, placed inside the
>    section. For example in the first  block
>   above, the ServerAlias directive indicates that the listed names are
>   other names which people can use to see that same web site:

```
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```

> then requests for all hosts in the example.com domain will be served
>   by the www.example.com virtual host. The wildcard characters * and ?
>   can be used to match names. Of course, you can't just make up names
>   and place them in ServerName or ServerAlias. **You must first have your
>   DNS server properly configured to map those names to an IP address
>   associated with your server.**

So basically if you want to redirect all **.com** requests you would do:

```
ServerAlias *.com
```